# How can i select a option from select form with a button?

Tags: php, html, forms

So i have a working form like this :

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
  <p>
    <label for="numbers"></label>
    <select name="select">
    <option selected disabled>Choose a trip</option>
      <option>Spain</option>
      <option>Paris</option>
      <option>Italy</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>Persons 
    <input type="text" name="numbers" id="numbers">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
  </p>
</form>
```

That form is located at: trips.html and have a post action with a process.php

Now i want too create a button, and if they press on that button they will go in the trips.html page (form page) and the option will be automaticcly selected.

So if this is my button:

```
<p>Click <a href="#goto_myform_and_select_option_spain">here </a>for Spain</p>
```

Then i want that if they press that button, the form page will be showed with the option Spain selected.

I don't get out with it, can somebody help me please?

Comment: I would do it with a combination of jQuery and PHP. Let me try to elaborate a demo...

Comment: So where is the code you have tried?

Comment: The problem is, I want to create a button in a wordpress website, and if they click on that button, the new page have to open with the selected option....

Comment: So i need something like this <a href="trips.html; select option:Spain">Click here for spain</a>

Comment: @sgtBOSE No i didn't try because i don't know how to make it work, can you help me sir?

Comment: Actually you only need PHP to do that. Check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the button like this to pass a variable in the URL:

```
<p>Click <a href="trips.php?selected=spain">here </a>for Spain</p>
```

I would need to change `trips.html` to `trips.php` so I could start using php on that file.

And finally I would need something like this in the form:

```
<option<?php if($_GET['selected'] == 'spain') echo ' selected'; ?>>Spain</option>
```

So `$_GET` is a php global var to grab variables from the URL.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much, i changed it to .php but i get no results : https://jsfiddle.net/waj1hqav/

Comment: It works you forget 1 thing and that was : > Thanks!  <option <?php if($_GET['selected'] == 'spain') echo 'selected'; ?> > Spain </option>